# Firefox not displaying PDF in primefaces p:media component on a remote server

Tags: pdf, firefox, primefaces

I have a JSF application that uses Primefaces 7.0. Some of its pages use the p:media component to display the content of PDF files. When installed on a remote linux server, the application does not show the content of the PDF if used with Firefox 67.0. It works fine with Chrome and IE. And it works perfectly on my Windows 10 PC, even with Firefox. To make it even wierder, inspecting the element makes it visible in my laptop, but not in my desktop computer. Has anyone else a similar problem? Please advice.

EDIT 11/11/2019: Today I learned that the problem occurs when using https instead of http. Therefore, **it doesn't really matter that the server is remote**; what happens is that on our remote (and public) server we use https

Comment: Possibly a Firefox bug?  Are you seeing any warnings or errors in the JS Console of Firefox when it does no appear?

Comment: It is possible; what baffles me is that the same app works even with firefox when running locally installed in my windows 10 PC. And it fails, consistently, when running in a remote server. I'll check the JS Console and be back to you with an  answer to your second question. One more piece of information: the remote server is slow; with Chrome and IE it takes a while to show the content of the PDF, but they do.

Comment: Form the JS Console
---
offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll viewer.js:2484:13
    scrollIntoView resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:2484
    _scrollIntoView resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:8730
    _scrollIntoView resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:8224
    scrollPageIntoView resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:8957
    setHash resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:6567
    setInitialView resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:1308
    load resource://pdf.js/web/viewer.js:1081

Comment: Form the JS Console---
PDF a207162df9655c04bc177fc1e0ef0869 [1.5 iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT / JasperReports Library version null] (PDF.js: 2.2.71) viewer.js:1195:15

Comment: And when I change the JS Console docking location, then the PDF contents becomes visible!

Comment: Are you using p:media or pe:documentViewer?

Comment: It uses p:media

Comment: I asked a friend to setup a similar application in their linux server, just to make sure it fails (or not) in another remote server. I'll let you know tomorrow.

Comment: So, did you find a solution?, I have de same issue. Chrome and Edge works, but Firefox not.

Comment: Sorry Angel, I haven't found a solution, yet.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet. Today I learned that the problem happens when using https instead of http. So it doesn't really matter that the server is remote; what is happening is that in our remote (and public) server we use https.